# parse.com expireAfterTimeInterval does not work in push notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have tried it in both Android and iOS code, and it simply does not set the Expiration date ever.   Anyone else had this issue?

Here is the code I used:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 60*60*2; // Two hours
[iOSPush expireAfterTimeInterval:interval];
```

Thanks,   Michael

Comment: how do you know it's not setting? Are you understanding what expire dates are used for?

Comment: Yes.  When I look in Parse they show if it is set.  It is listed as "None".   If I use their other command, expireAtDate, sets that field. But that command requires the devices time to be accurate or the expired time can be off.

Comment: Works fine for me (code: http://pastebin.com/F4cDXX64). Are you using the latest version of the Parse iOS SDK (v1.6.4)? If yes, file a bug at parse.com/help, if not download the latest version, test again and file a bug if the problem still exists.

Comment: Bjorn: Thanks!  That was it, the newer framework did it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be on to a bug -

After doing the recommended steps from their iOS guide here : https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-expiry/iOS

I concluded with the same results as you, 'None' for expiry date. I even used their own exact example. Additionally, I tried using `setData`, not using `setData` and even replicated their own example in its entirety with no results.

Their [SDK Reference](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFPush.html#//api/name/expireAfterTimeInterval:) doesn't provide any minimum or special requirements so I feel it's a bug on their end.

For now, to circumvent the issue you can do the following:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 60*60*2; // Two hours
NSDate *dateFromInterval = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];

//Set expiry back to a date
[iOSPush expireAtDate:dateFromInterval];
```

---

**Edit** : I just posted this on Parses google group, I don't have a Facebook account to report a bug so you could either report one for us or disregard in general. 
It seems coincidentally, we both are using outdated Parse framework versions and this bug is targeted or circumstantial. I normally like to wait to upgrade frameworks to see if my projects are effected, but I downloaded the starter project from Parse.com and tested it out with 1.6.4 and it's all in working order. Up to you at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the framework to the current PARSE framework solved the issue.   Clearly that command was buggy in prior PARSE frameworks.